# Spivak, Ch. 25, "Complex Numbers", Problem 8a: If $c$ is an integer and not a perfect square, is $\sqrt{c}$ irrational?

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers, proof-explanation

> 8. (a) Let $c$ be an integer which is not the square of another integer. If $a$ and $b$ are integers we define the conjugate of
>    $a+b\sqrt{c}$, denoted by $\overline{a+b\sqrt{c}}$ as $a-b\sqrt{c}$.
>    Show that the conjugate is well defined by showing that a number can
>    be written $a+b\sqrt{c}$, for integers $a$ and $b$, in only one way.

Here is the solution manual solution to this item

> Suppose that $a+b\sqrt{c}=a'+b'\sqrt{c}$. If $b=b'$, then also $a=a'$.
> If $b\neq b'$ then we would have $\sqrt{c}=(a-a')/(b-b')$,
> contradicting the fact that $\sqrt{c}$ is irrational (Problem 2-17).

First of all, there is a typo above, correct? It should be $\sqrt{c}=-\frac{a-a'}{b-b'}$.

My question is about this application of the result from Problem 2-17. In that problem we prove multiple things (four items in that problem). I think the relevant one being cited is the following

- for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $\sqrt n$ is irrational unless $n=m^2, m\in\mathbb{N}$.

Here is the proof of this statement

> Assume $\sqrt{n}$ is rational. Then $\sqrt{n}=\frac{a}{b}$,
> $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$.
>
> Since $n\in\mathbb{N}$ then $\sqrt{n}>0$ and we can write
> $a=b\sqrt{n}$. Then $$a^2=b^2\cdot n$$
>
> We can factorize each side into a product of prime numbers. On the
> lefthand side, since we are squaring $a$ then each prime in its
> factorization appears twice. Thus, the factors on the righthand side
> must also appear twice. Now, we already get pairs of factors in $b^2$.
> Thus, $n$ must be composed of pairs of factors, which means it is a
> perfect square.
>
> Thus, if $n$ is not a perfect square, then by contrapositive we know
> that $\sqrt{n}$ is irrational.

The thing is, how do we know that $\sqrt{c}$ is irrational if $c$ is an integer? That is, in particular, if $c$ is negative?

The result above (2-17) doesn't seem to apply in this case does it? It's strange because the solution manual seems to imply it does.

Comment: Well, even if 8(a) did not intend to include negative $c$, it is still true.  If $c<0$ we have $\sqrt{c}$ is not real, and in particular not rational.

Comment: So your argument is that if $c$ is a non-perfect square integer then either it is positive and hence irrational by 2-17, or it is negative and hence complex, thus non-real thus non-irrational? Does this line of reasoning include: (i) a rational number is a real number that can be expressed as a ratio of integers; (ii) any real number that cannot is irrational? If this is the caes, it is not obvious to me that there aren't numbers that are non-real and irrational.

Comment: If $c < 0$, the equation $\sqrt{c} = - \frac{a-a'}{b-b'}$ has a real number on the right and a purely imaginary number on the left. That's a contradiction regardless of whether you want to consider certain complex numbers as irrational.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I agree with your sign correction of the typo.

In Spivak's solution for 8.a, "$\sqrt c$ is irrational" cannot mean anything else than "$\sqrt c$ is not a quotient of two integers". Spivak's definition of irrational numbers has to include non-real complex numbers since in 8.a, the integer $c$ may be negative.

In 8.a, he uses 2.17 if $c>0,$ and needs nothing if $c<0.$